# Send Post request with parameters in URL

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, ionic3

After any sign up I push the user to verify his account. I send the verification code to his email and he adds it in input and sends that value by post API call. 
My problem is when I make a request I get a response with 203 Non-Authoritative Information. But when I try this process with PostMan it works fine

My Componant Code :

```
  verfiy(){

  this.code = this.userverfiycode.verfiCode;


this.authService.postData('Verify?userId='+this.user +'&vCode='+ this.code ).then((result) => {

  this.responseData = result;
  console.log(this.responseData);
  console.log(this.user);
  console.log(this.code);
  console.log(this.type);



  if (this.responseData = true) {

    this.pushpage()

  }

  else{

    console.log("");

      }
    }, (err) => {
     // Error log


    });

 }
```

my Provider Code :

```
 let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:50494/api/Account/';
 let apiKey = 'sdf4rw-23fs-3454-fsdsd-3we2693243424';


 @Injectable()
 export class AuthProvider {




 constructor(public http : Http) {
 console.log('Hello AuthService Provider');



}

UserKey = localStorage.getItem('loginData');


postData( type) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('token', apiKey);
  headers.append('api_key', this.UserKey);



   this.http.post(apiUrl + type, {headers: headers})
     .subscribe(res => {


      resolve();
      console.log()

    }, (err) => {
      reject(err);
      console.log()


    });
  });
}
```

Comment: can you post the post code here too

Comment: there is no body in the post data. Is this correct?

Comment: I want to send parameters only in  the Url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generally, the second parameter of **post()** is data and third is {headers};

Can you try sending some dummy data

```
this.http.post(apiUrl + type, {}, {headers: headers})
     .subscribe(res => {});
```

I thinking so because the backend is not getting the headers you are sending in the post() function.

Can you please check your devtool network tab for this request, if the `Request Headers` are going properly or not

Comment: Just remember that post() 2nd parameter is body/form-date, and in 3rd parameter we send options. Since in your case the form-data is empty so send empty object. I hope you understand the logic

Comment: Please accept this answer as correct, it may help other having similar issue.